# Adding SSOProfiles in spring-security using opensaml library

Tags: authentication, saml, saml-2.0, opensaml, wso2-identity-server

I am learning SAML implementation, and I went through the spring-security saml sample, Currently as the AuthRequest which is getting generated is happening by default, I am trying to customize my authRequest.

I have been going through the opensaml libraries and was trying to implement **WebSSOProfilesImpl** class, where in the **getAuthnRequest()** i have implemented the following code.

```
protected AuthnRequest getAuthnRequest(SAMLMessageContext context, WebSSOProfileOptions options,
                                       AssertionConsumerService assertionConsumer,
                                       SingleSignOnService bindingService) throws SAMLException, MetadataProviderException {

    SAMLObjectBuilder<AuthnRequest> builder = 
            (SAMLObjectBuilder<AuthnRequest>) builderFactory.getBuilder
            (new QName("urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:profile:saml2.0:v2:schema:protocol:wd-13", "XACMLAuthzDecisionQueryType",
                "xacml-samlp"));
    System.out.println("Builder : "+builder.toString()+" "+builder);
    AuthnRequest request = builder.buildObject();
    System.out.println("request : "+request.toString());
    request.setIsPassive(options.getPassive());
    request.setForceAuthn(options.getForceAuthN());
    request.setProviderName(options.getProviderName());
    request.setVersion(SAMLVersion.VERSION_20);

    buildCommonAttributes(context.getLocalEntityId(), request, bindingService);

    buildScoping(request, bindingService, options);
    builNameIDPolicy(request, options);
    buildAuthnContext(request, options);
    buildReturnAddress(request, assertionConsumer);

    return request;

}
```

But while Logging into my IS which i am using as IDP, i am getting NullPointerException in **SAMLObjectBuilder** object. Am i doing anything wrong?? please help, any help is highly appreciated!!!.

**NOTE:**
The values which i have passed inside QName is what I want to give for which i can follow XACML-SAML decision query use case.

Comment: Hi, have you called DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap()?

Comment: i have seen it before but dont know where exactly to implement

Answer (score 0):

You can find the sample from here

https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vdenotaris/spring/boot/security/saml/web/config/WebSecurityConfig.java

Comment: **@Bean
    public WebSSOProfileOptions defaultWebSSOProfileOptions() {
        WebSSOProfileOptions webSSOProfileOptions = new WebSSOProfileOptions();
        webSSOProfileOptions.setIncludeScoping(false);
        return webSSOProfileOptions;
    }**  see this is using default Options i want to add saml profile of xacml, that is why i am trying to ovverride this method. but failing to understand how to do it